# Can GAP test, if two ordinary character tables are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-mathematics, gap, computer-algebra-systems

I'd like to ask the following question:

> Is there a way to let GAP test, if two (previously with GAP computed) ordinary character tables are isomorphic?

Here, two ordinary character tables shall be called isomorphic, if you can permute the rows and columns of one character table to get the other one.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know what it means for two groups to be isomorphic. I don't know what it means for two character tables to be isomorphic.

Comment: I have not heard of this either. Perhaps it just means that you can permute the rows and columns of one to get the other?

Comment: And ... non-isomorphic groups can have the _same_ character table!

Comment: Ad Gerry Myerson and Derek Holt: Thank you for the comment. I have edited the question.

Comment: The question of determining whether two graphs are isomorphic amounts to determining whether two zero-one matrices can be obtained from each other by permuting rows and columns, and no one knows an efficient algorithm for that. I suspect this character table question is no easier.

Comment: In his Journal of Algebra paper "Answer to a question of R. Brauer" Dade called the character tables isomorphic. Hence, I stole the notion.   :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `TransformingPermutationsCharacterTables` does exactly what you want. Manual at
https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap71.html#X7B0A669484470D09

Comment: Hm...Do you happen to know, why the following does not work? gap> G:=QuaternionGroup(8);
<pc group of size 8 with 3 generators>
gap> H:=DihedralGroup(8);
<pc group of size 8 with 3 generators>
gap> ctG:=CharacterTable(G);
CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> )
gap> ctH:=CharacterTable(H);
CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> )
gap> T:=TransformingPermutationsCharacterTables(ctG,ctH);
fail

Comment: But contimuing with gap> IrrQ8:=Irr(ctG);
[ Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ), Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, -1, -1, 1, 1 ] ), 
  Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, -1, 1, 1, -1 ] ), Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, 1, -1, 1, -1 ] ), 
  Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 2, 0, 0, -2, 0 ] ) ]
...

Comment: ...and gap> IrrD8:=Irr(ctH);
[ Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] ), Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, -1, 1, 1, -1 ] ), 
  Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, 1, -1, 1, -1 ] ), Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 1, -1, -1, 1, 1 ] ), 
  Character( CharacterTable( <pc group of size 8 with 3 generators> ), [ 2, 0, 0, -2, 0 ] ) ]
...

Comment: gap> TransformingPermutations(IrrQ8,IrrD8);
rec( columns := (), group := Group([ (3,5), (2,3) ]), rows := (2,4,3) )
works...hm...

Comment: Ah ok, in the manual it is written that TransformingPermutationsCharacterTables tries to construct a permutation $\pi$ that transforms the set of rows of the matrix Irr( tbl1 ) to the set of rows of the matrix Irr( tbl2 ) by permuting the columns, such that $\pi$ transforms also the power maps and the element orders.